# Successful test run in Vitest end with error. Returning Unhandled Errors and Uncaught Exception

Tags: react-testing-library, apexcharts, vitest, react-apexcharts

Vitest: 0.34.4
apexcharts: ~3.41.0
react-apexcharts: ~1.4.1
React: ~18.2.0
Ubuntu 22.04

Hi guys. I got here strange error. While my tests all end up with success I got err on the screen anyway. I already tried dangerouslyIgnoreUnhandledErrors or unmount() in component and many other solutions. Nothing worked. Any idea?
I try to test my apexcharts running on React.

```
 ✓ src/react-ui/test/components/DeleteModal.test.tsx (4)
 ✓ src/react-ui/test/components/TableIdsSelectable.test.tsx (1)
 ✓ src/react-ui/test/components/TableRadio.test.tsx (1)
 ✓ src/react-ui/test/components/TableNotClickable.test.tsx (1)
 ✓ src/react-ui/test/components/TableCheckboxes.test.tsx (1) 425ms
 ✓ src/react-ui/test/components/Text.test.tsx (2)
 ✓ src/react-ui/test/components/Select.test.tsx (3) 477ms
 ✓ src/react-ui/test/components/Number.test.tsx (2)
 ✓ src/test/components/SubscriptionThickBarChart.test.tsx (1)

Uncaught Exception 
TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')
 ❯ t node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.common.js:10:9056
 ❯ Et.a.PathArray.morph node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.common.js:10:12451
 ❯ create.initAnimations node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.common.js:6:422898
 ❯ create.startCurrent node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.common.js:6:422208
 ❯ create.start node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.common.js:6:422007
 ❯ create.<anonymous> node_modules/apexcharts/dist/apexcharts.common.js:6:426560
 ❯ listOnTimeout node:internal/timers:559:17
 ❯ processTimers node:internal/timers:502:7

  Test Files  9 passed (9)
      Tests  16 passed (16)
     Errors  1 error
   Start at  12:59:57
   Duration  3.32s (transform 770ms, setup 853ms, collect 12.86s, tests 2.14s, environment 3.08s, prepare 1.28s)
```

this is basically my test:

```
/* eslint-disable @typescript-eslint/no-empty-function */
import React from 'react';
import * as LocalQuery from '../../generated/RestUtilities2';
import * as LocalCurrentId from '../../utils/useCurrentId';
import { _MockSelector } from '../../react-ui/test/components/_MockRedux';
import { afterEach, beforeAll, describe, it, vi, expect } from 'vitest';
import ApexCharts from 'apexcharts';
import { render, waitFor } from '@testing-library/react';
import { BaseThickBarChart } from '../../components/charts/SubscriptionThickBarChart';
import '@testing-library/jest-dom';

vi.mock('apexcharts', async () => {
  const actual = (await vi.importActual('apexcharts')) as object;
  return {
    ...actual,
    exec: vi.fn(() => {
      return new Promise((resolve) => {
        resolve('uri');
      });
    })
  };
});

Object.defineProperty(window, 'ResizeObserver', {
  writable: true,
  value:
    window.ResizeObserver ||
    vi.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
      observe: vi.fn(),
      unobserve: vi.fn(),
      disconnect: vi.fn()
    }))
});

Object.defineProperty(global.SVGElement.prototype, 'getScreenCTM', {
  writable: true,
  value: vi.fn(() => 10)
});

Object.defineProperty(global.SVGElement.prototype, 'getBBox', {
  writable: true,
  value: vi.fn().mockReturnValue({
    x: 10,
    y: 10
  })
});

Object.defineProperty(global.SVGElement.prototype, 'getComputedTextLength', {
  writable: true,
  value: vi.fn().mockReturnValue(10)
});

Object.defineProperty(global.SVGElement.prototype, 'createSVGMatrix', {
  writable: true,
  value: vi.fn().mockReturnValue({
    x: 10,
    y: 10,
    inverse: () => 'what',
    multiply: () => 'hej'
  })
});

window.ResizeObserver = vi.fn().mockImplementation(() => ({
  disconnect: vi.fn(),
  observe: vi.fn(),
  unobserve: vi.fn()
}));

ApexCharts.prototype.destroy = vi.fn();

describe('Table Range chart', () => {
  try {
    beforeAll(() => {
      global.ResizeObserver = class ResizeObserver {
        observe() {}
        unobserve() {}
        disconnect() {}
      };
    });

    afterEach(() => {
      vi.restoreAllMocks();
    });

    vi.mock('react-redux', () => ({
      ...vi.importActual('react-redux'),
      useSelector: vi.fn(() => _MockSelector)
    }));
    vi.spyOn(LocalQuery, 'useQuery').mockReturnValue({
      call: () =>
        new Promise((resolve) =>
          resolve({
            status: 200,
            content: [
              {
                name: 'plan1',
                partNumber: 'part-plan1',
                price: 1000.0,
                currency: 0,
                validFrom: '2024-09-27T22:21:27.782Z',
                validTo: '2024-10-27T22:21:27.782Z',
                status: 0,
                id: 'AgLD'
              }
            ]
          })
        ),
      data: {
        status: 200
      },
      loading: false,
      refetch: () => new Promise((resolve) => resolve())
    });
    vi.spyOn(LocalCurrentId, 'useCurrentId').mockReturnValue('');
  } catch (error) {
    expect(error).toBeInstanceOf(TypeError);
    expect(error).toHaveProperty('message', 'Cannot read properties of undefined');
  }

  it('Checking SubscriptionThickBarChart', async () => {
    try {
      const { container, rerender, unmount } = render(<BaseThickBarChart buttons={[{ title: '30 days', value: 1 }]} />);
      await waitFor(() => rerender(<BaseThickBarChart buttons={[{ title: '30 days', value: 1 }]} />));
      const chartSubscription = container?.querySelector('path[val="1730067687782"]');
      expect(chartSubscription).toBeInTheDocument();
      unmount();
    } catch (error) {
      expect(error).toBeInstanceOf(TypeError);
      console.log('error :>> ', error);
      // expect(error).toHaveProperty('message', 'Cannot read properties of undefined');
    }
  });
});
```

will be glad for any idea how to solve it. It will be acceptable only If this error skip and that it